# Fail to Read File In Mule Standalone Server

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

Hi I am working with Mule Standalone server and when i am deploying my application as a ZIP to Standalone server as mentioned in the [Mule Website Deployment Structure](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Application+Format). In my project structure i have one file inside 
`src/main/resources/myfolder/myfile.xml`.

When i am reading this file from Anypoint Studio using `System.getProperty("user.dir")` it is working fine .

When i am reading deploying the same in Standalone server it is throwing file not found exception, because their `System.getProperty("user.dir")` is returning till bin where file not exist `\Java\MuleStandAlone\bin`.

So to deploy to Mule Standalone where i will place my files so that i can read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

files under src/main/resources will be available from the classpath, so there should be no reason to lookup the root directory.
Just read it from classpath as "myfolder/myfile.xml".

E.g:

```
<set-payload value="#[Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream('myfolder/myfile.xml')]" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the way as Ryan Carter mention in the answer works for me and reading path as a String instead of Stream that also works for me.

```html
String path= MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("myfolder/myfile.xml").getPath();
```